# How to delete rows based on character number of occurrences?

Tags: r

Im requiring to delete all the rows which have less than 6 underscores on its value

my data

```
id var1                            var2
1  procedures_1_1_5___240          TRUE
2  procedures___6                  TRUE
3  procedures_1_20_1___2130        TRUE
4  procedures_1_1___2              TRUE
```

my desired output

```
id var1                            var2
1  procedures_1_1_5___240          TRUE
3  procedures_1_20_1___2130        TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_count` on the 'var1' to find the number of '_' and `filter` rows where the count is greater than or equal to 6

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   filter(str_count(var1, "_") >= 6)
```

-output

```
  id                     var1 var2
1  1   procedures_1_1_5___240 TRUE
2  3 procedures_1_20_1___2130 TRUE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:4, var1 = c("procedures_1_1_5___240", 
"procedures___6", 
"procedures_1_20_1___2130", "procedures_1_1___2"), var2 = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Answer (score 4):

In base R you could do:

```
subset(df1, nchar(gsub('[^_]', '', var1)) >= 6)

  id                     var1 var2
1  1   procedures_1_1_5___240 TRUE
3  3 procedures_1_20_1___2130 TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

`Base R`: Here is an alternative using `lengths` with `regmatches` and `gregexpr` from `base R`:

```
df1[lengths(regmatches(df1$var1, gregexpr("_", df1$var1))) >=6,]

Or short form:
lengths(gregexpr('_', df1$var1))
 Provided by Onyambu (many thanks)
```

```
  id                     var1 var2
1  1   procedures_1_1_5___240 TRUE
2  3 procedures_1_20_1___2130 TRUE
```

Comment: `lengths(gregexpr('_', df1$var1))` should be sufficient